# Must I test the release build which I submit to Apple? How?

Tags: iphone, app-store, adhoc

I've heard you gotta test the release build as well, and some things can work different in that build than on the debug build. The big question is, how can I bring a release build on my device without the App Store route? Only by Ad Hoc distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a third build configuration in addition to Debug & Release by copying the Release configuration and changing **only** the code signing to use the distribution signing key for the app.  Call the third one "Distribution."  By basing the distribution off the "release" build, the two will be identical save for the code signing.

Now, you just need to test the "release" build on your device and when you're happy it works, build the "distribution" and submit that build to Apple.

Comment: Can yo go into more detail? Apple had instructed me to duplicate the debug configuration and call that "Distribution". There, I had to set that distribution signing key, which Apple says doesn't run on the device. Not that AdHoc one. So there's a way I can test that distribution build without using AdHoc?

Comment: My Debug build profiles include `-DDEBUG` to enable all the `#ifdef DEBUG` sections of code and does not compile with the optimizer.  My Release configuration uses the optimizer and disables the debug code.  You can base Distribution off Debug, but I'd rather base Distribution off the Release configuration.  That said, do what's best for your app.  Apple is correct that the distribution signing key does not allow for directly installing the app.  The distribution signing key is specifically for submitting to Apple.